# Вопрос по dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Есть базовая логика jquery для дропдаун менюшки. Попробуйте быстро переводить мышкой с одной красной записи на другую, а затем уведите её в сторону. В итоге дропдаун будет багаться и поочередно открывать то одно, то другое. Как сделать так, чтобы сначала закрылось одно, а потом открылось другое ? Или иной способ решения

```js
$(".has-dropdown")
    .mouseover(function() {
        $(".category-sub-menu",this).fadeIn(300);
    });
$(".has-dropdown")
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $(".category-sub-menu",this).fadeOut(300);
    });
```

```css
.category-area {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.category-menu {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    /*margin: 30px 0;*/
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.category-menu > li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 30px 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 16.6666666667%;
    transition: all .3s;
}
.category-menu > li > a {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;
    color: var(--heading-color);
}
.category-menu > li > a img {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.category-menu .category-sub-menu {
    display: none;
    padding: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 15px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 15px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 9;
    /*-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;*/
    /*transition: all 0.4s ease;*/
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -10px);
    transform: translate(0, -10px);
    top: 100px;
}
.nav-right-part ul li span {
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: var(--heading-color);
    -webkit-transform: translate(100%, -45%);
    transform: translate(100%, -45%);
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="category-menu">
    <li class="category-wrap"><a href="shop.html">Суши</a></li>
    <li class="category-wrap"><a href="shop.html">Роллы</a></li>
    <li class="category-wrap has-dropdown">
        <a href="shop.html" style="color: red">Пицца</a>
        <div class="category-sub-menu">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    1
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    2
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    3
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    4
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="category-wrap has-dropdown"><a href="shop.html" style="color: red">Напитки</a>
        <div class="category-sub-menu">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    3
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    2
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    3
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    4
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: без js, с помощью css hover'ом, вас устраивает?

Comment: @HTOHOT если там не надо создавать фантомный бордюр (границу прозрачную), чтобы дропдаун не закрывался, то буду рад взглянуть )

Comment: Ну вот к примеру, в интернете их куча https://codepen.io/cassidoo/pen/bGbVoJQ

Comment: @HTOHOT ну вот у этих куча меню есть один существенный минус, который я написал )) Если отступ(margin) увеличить для дропдауна, то это меню будет закрываться как только курсор попытается перейти на сам дропдаун, а делать для такого случая transparent верхнюю границу..ну такое

Answer (score 0):

Я очень надеюсь, что это у вас не комерческией проект, и вы не получите за эту работу денег, поскольку это очень топорный подход с просадкой по памяти. Вот решение вашей проблемы, через использование метода [.stop()](https://html5css.ru/jquery/jquery_stop.php)

```js
$(".has-dropdown")
    .mouseover(function() {
     $(".category-sub-menu",this).stop(true).fadeIn(300)
      })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $(".category-sub-menu",this).stop(true).fadeOut(300);
    });
```

```css
.category-area {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.category-menu {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    /*margin: 30px 0;*/
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.category-menu > li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 30px 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 16.6666666667%;
    transition: all .3s;
}
.category-menu > li > a {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;
    color: var(--heading-color);
}
.category-menu > li > a img {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.category-menu .category-sub-menu {
    display: none;
    padding: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 15px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 15px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 9;
    /*-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;*/
    /*transition: all 0.4s ease;*/
    border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -10px);
    transform: translate(0, -10px);
    top: 100px;
}
.nav-right-part ul li span {
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: var(--heading-color);
    -webkit-transform: translate(100%, -45%);
    transform: translate(100%, -45%);
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="category-menu">
    <li class="category-wrap"><a href="shop.html">Суши</a></li>
    <li class="category-wrap"><a href="shop.html">Роллы</a></li>
    <li class="category-wrap has-dropdown">
        <a href="shop.html" style="color: red">Пицца</a>
        <div class="category-sub-menu">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    1
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    2
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    3
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    4
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="category-wrap has-dropdown"><a href="shop.html" style="color: red">Напитки</a>
        <div class="category-sub-menu">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    3
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    2
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    3
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    4
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Это скорее для самообразования. Решил через .hover и :not(:animated). А в чем просадка заключается ?

Comment: В том что плагин отрабатывает по всем элементам сразу и при ваших целях, ещё и должен обрывать прошлый вызов. Ваша задача спокойно решается css свойствами... но раз вопрос не о том был.